# How to use xpath/css selectors when the website has two root html elements?

Tags: python, html, css, selenium, xpath

I am using Python, selenium webdriver, IE, xpath and css to get some report from the internet.
The problem is that the website has two html elements :

```
<html></html>
<html lang="en"></html>
```

I know that the element I'm interested in lives in this first html block.
However, the webdriver does not "see" this first html element.
I can access the elements of this second html lang="en" without a problem via either css or xpath, but
every find_elements_by_xpath/find_elements_by_css_selector query to this first html element returns empty list.

How can I refer to this first html element ?

I tried :

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('html:nth-of-type(1)')
```

And I tried this :

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('html[1]')
```

And I also tried this :

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('html:not([lang="en"])')
```

But neither of those have worked, all return an empty list.

Comment: That is not valid HTML as far as I know. So you can't change it to be valid in the first place?

Comment: My guess is that one or both of these HTML elements are in an IFRAME, likely the first given your description. You should check that. Is it possible to share the URL?

Comment: JeffC, thanks for suggestion, but it's not in  the iframe. There are just 2 html elements at the very top of the website. Unfortunately I can't share url. It's as if it was composed of 2 separate websites, of example the search box which is at the top of the page leaves in this second html lang="en" element, but the filters which I need to adjust to generate report leaves in this first html element which I can't access.

Answer (score -1):

If you're looking for the first one, you've to keep in mind, they are 0-index-based:

```py
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('html[0]')
```

But probably the problem is, that html is considered the root element. And since there are two root elements, it might not work.

Comment: XPath is not *0-index-based*